# Proving that $\int_a^b\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}}=\pi$

Tags: real-analysis

How do I prove that 
$$\int_a^b\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}}=\pi?$$
I'm just wondering if LHS even equal to the RHS in the first place? 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What if $a=b=0$?

Comment: @M.B. Who cares? =)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Hint:  Substitute $x=a\cos^2\phi+b\sin^2\phi$.

(Quite an overkill solution ...)

Comment: This is such a brilliant substitution!

Comment: Amazing, may I ask how you came up with this substitution?

Comment: I'm having two analysis class right now ...

Comment: Certainly they've done you some good. (+1)

Answer (score 9):

Hint:$$\int_a^b{(u-a)^{x-1}(b-v)^{y-1}}=(b-a)^{x+y-1}\frac{\Gamma(x).\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$

> $$\int_a^b\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}}=(b-a)^{\frac12+\frac12-1}\frac{\Gamma(\frac12).\Gamma(\frac12)}{\Gamma(1)}=\pi$$

Answer (score 5):

Here is another method using square completion:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^b \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}}&=\int_a^b \frac{dx}{\sqrt{-\left(x^2-(a+b)x+ab\right)}}\\
&=\int_a^b \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}(a-b)^2-\left(x-\frac{b}{2}-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2}} \, \text{square completion}\\
&=\int_{\frac{a-b}{2}}^{\frac{b-a}{2}}\frac{2du}{\sqrt{(a-b)^2-4u^2}}, \,\text{substituing } u=x-b/2-a/2
\end{align}
$$
Let $u=\frac{(a-b)}{2}\sin(v)$ to complete.